# How to make apache storm as FIPS (Federal Information Processing Standard ) compliant

Tags: apache-storm

Could someone please let me know on how to make apache storm as FIPS compliant ?
I did not find online info around this.I could find it for zookeeper
https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/pull/1482

Thanks,
Sarita

Comment: Why do you think it is not?

Comment: Best to ask on the user list